# What is a good GeoTiff Viewer?

Tags: viewer, geotiff

I'm working with GeoTiff related files and would like to know what's a good viewer to see the outcome of my work? It needs to work on a Windows machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ERViewer from ERMapper was good, you need to register now to get it from ERDAS:

https://download.hexagongeospatial.com/downloads/imagine/erdas-er-viewer-2014-v14-01
Irfanview can also open GeoTIFF, but won't be as efficient for very large files.

OpenEV in the GDAL suite will also display GeoTIFF: http://openev.sourceforge.net/ - GDAL is very helpful in general for GeoTIFF.

Manifold 9.0 is also very good, there's a free viewer for use on Windows. http://www.manifold.net/viewer.shtml

Comment: Manifold Viewer (9.0) doesn't seem to support tiff format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does

Answer (score 2):

You can also use uDig for viewing GeoTiff (and other GIS-data): http://udig.refractions.net/

uDig - User-friendly Desktop Internet GIS: A GIS Framework for Eclipse

uDig is an open source (LGPL) desktop application framework, built with Eclipse Rich Client (RCP) technology.

- uDig can be used as a stand-alone application.
- uDig can be extended with RCP “plug-ins”.
- uDig can be used as a plug-in in an existing RCP application.

Comment: uDig for windows has deteriorated and appears to be unsupported.  You can install it but as I found, and other users confirm dating back a few years it won't run.